# Is it possible to modify a .cs file in the App_Code directory at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, webforms, enums

I have a file in the App_Code directory called Permissions.cs which stores an enum of the various permission id numbers.  I was wondering if it would be possible to modify this enum via the System.IO.File class during runtime.  Can anyone enlighten me on if this is possible, and if it is not then why?

Comment: I don't know, but there is surely a better solution to your problem than modifying the code at runtime.

Comment: This question scares me in so many ways...

Comment: Modify it, sure, no problem.  I assume however that because its an Enum, you'd then want to load it into your assembly.  Also doable, but its a pain it the butt.  Maybe a better idea is to post the reason for doing such a silly thing and we can help figure out a better way.

Comment: Why don't you put those values in a List<T> or some other collection that maybe suits you better and use that? Changing the code at runtime is wrong in so many ways and opens your app to vulnerabilities.

Comment: GregoryHouseMD, could you tell me what kind of vulnerabilities that this behavior would open my application to?

Comment: @JustinRoss Without seeing the exact use case for your requirement.. its hard to give you specific vulnerabilities. However, you can potentially open yourself up to runtime crashes because your code doesn't actually compile. Are you willing to trust your string manipulation abilities? I certainly wouldn't.. and I think I'm fairly good with string parsing/manipulation.